# Listen only to changes in document instead of all the time

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to only listen to changes in a document in firebase, but now it seems it is listening every moment although there is no changes. I can see that because when I print it to the console it never stops.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

  Map firestoreInfo = documentSnapshot.data();
  setState(() {
    name = firestoreInfo['name'];
  });
});
```

Could anyone help here? Also, it seems there is no "documentChanges" method for me I can call on the document snapshot data.

Comment: In what part of the code have you written this code?

Comment: You should check for the change by if name != firestoreInfo['name']

Comment: Simply, you can not

Answer (score 4):

When you attach a listener to Firestore it initially fires with the current value of the document from the database. It then fires whenever the document changes. There is no way to skip the initial value of a listener.

A common way to get the behavior you want is to:

1. Store a `lastUpdated` timestamp field in the user document(s).
2. Use a query to only return documents where `lastUpdated` is after "now".
3. To perform such a query on a document with a specific ID, you'll need to use a condition on [`FieldPath.documentId`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this if you use a QuerySnapshot

There is a DocumentChange<Object?> that has the properties of the change.

See [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentChange).

There is a change type for a modified document - `docChange.Type == DocumentChangeType.modified`

and you can see the new values of the document using-

```
 docChange.document
```

Code-

```
  Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where("userId", isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .limit(1)

  query.snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot<Object?> event) {
    for (var change in event.docChanges) {
      if (change.doc.data() != null  && change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified){
        print('Document data: ${change.doc.data()}');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist');
      }
    }
  });
```